# Window won't popup in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUjQrThw-ss

I use xampp to test it out.

The problem is that the window won't popup there.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Html5 Drawing App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style='margin: 0'>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="rad">
            Radius <span id="radval">10</span>
            <div id="decRad" class="radcontrol">-</div>
            <div id="incRad" class="radcontrol">+</div>
        </div>
        <div id="colors">
        </div>
        <div id="save">
        Save
        </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">
        Sorry, Your Browser Is Unsupported. Switch To Another Browser
    </canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="radius.js"></script>
    <script src="colors.js"></script>
    <script src="save.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**save.js:**

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveImage);

function saveImage(){
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status = 200){
            //do our stuff
            var response = request.responseText;
            window.open(response, '_blank', 'location=0, menubar=0');
        }
    }

    request.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-ww-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('img='+data);


    //window.open(data, '_blank', 'location=0, menubar=0'); 
}
```

**save.php:**

```
<?php

$data = $_POST_['img'];

$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);

$img = base64_decode($data);

$path = 'images/' . uniqid() . '.png';
if(file_put_contents($path, $img)){
    print $path;
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
}

?>
```

Why isnt it popping up?
Using Google Chromes developer tools, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment save.js:11
POST http://localhost/draw/save.php 500 (Internal Server Error) save.js:20
3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? Did you try my suggestions below ?

Comment: It is also customary to upvote the accepted answer, since (by definition) you believe it is a good answer that successfully addresses the problem at hand :D Just saying...

Comment: I can't upvote answers as I only got 3 rep out of the 20 needed

Comment: I always forget about such limitations :) It's OK, I am just letting you know, so you know what to do in the future (when you have enough reps !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing the following errors:

```
if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status = 200){
                                             Λ
                                             |___ ==

request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-ww-form-urlencoded');
                                                        Λ
                                                        |___ www

$data = $_POST_['img'];
           Λ
           |___ $_POST[...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted an equal sgn in this line:

```
if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status = 200){
                                             ^   should be ==
```

Comment: Oh, I have? Apparently I did.. Thanks

Comment: Well, now it gives me this error: POST http://localhost/draw/save.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 server error is a problem with the server-side code. That's a different problem. Look at your server's error log.

Comment: I looked at the php_error.log file and this is what it says: [28-Oct-2013 05:19:11 Europe/Stockholm] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _POST_ in C:\xampp\htdocs\draw\save.php on line 3

Comment: I found it. I failed.. It went to     $POST_ instead of     $POST

Comment: Now, i fixed some errors..

But..

Chrome error:

    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

PHP error file:

    [28-Oct-2013 05:21:45 Europe/Stockholm] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: img in C:\xampp\htdocs\draw\save.php on line 3